# How to take UTC time and add 30 minutes and return the output using groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy and I'm trying to parse UTC date and add 30 min. I'm expecting the output to be 2018-01-22T12:41:00.000Z. But the output is 2018-01-22T00:41:00.000Z. There is something going on with 12 and 24 hour format. Much appreciate the help.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def TxnTm = '2018-01-22T12:11:00.000Z';
def inputString = TxnTm;
def formatString = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S'Z'";

def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
def date = sdf.parse(inputString) ;

println date;

use( TimeCategory ) {
    after30Mins = date + 30.minutes;
}

def today = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
return today.format(after30Mins)
```

Comment: You on Java 8?  You can get rid of SimpleDateFormat if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing from below statement

```
def today = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

To:

```
def today = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z')
```

You can quickly try it online [demo](https://ideone.com/iTI3jp)

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. lower case "hh" made the difference.